# how to set OracleCommand.BindByName =true in .net?

Tags: .net, oracle, visual-studio, odp.net, system.data.oracleclient

Environment:

-Visual Studio 2010 (.NET FrameWork 4)

- ASP.NET web Application
- Oracle Database
- using System.Data.OracleClient

I have a web form where a user can enter any or no data into text boxes corresponding to each parameter in my query.if user entered no data the text box will get "0" value.

here is my query:

SELECT "CardNo" , "Name"
FROM CardList
WHERE("CardNo"=:CardNo or :CardNo=0) and ("Name"=:Name or :Name=0)

when I right click on the query from the table adapter in the MYDATABASE.xsd panel, and select 'Preview Data' and fill parameter values with "0" i get the error (" ORA-01008 : Not all variables bound" ). After a lot of searching i found out that i should set OracleCommand.BindByName =true (apparently it is not true by default)

can anyone help me how to do it?

Comment: System.Data.OracleClient is *NOT* ODP.NET. System.Data.OracleClient already binds by name. Which provider are you really using?

Answer (score 0):

Use Oracle.ManagedDataAccess instead of System.Data.OracleClient that is deprecated

Create a command objet :

```
using(Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleConnection connection = new Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleConnection(myConnectionString))
{
    connection.Open();
    Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleCommand command = new    Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleCommand();
    command.CommandText = "SELECT ..."
    command.BindByName = true;
    // execute your command
    ...
}
```